# Force Quick Look to treat .in files like .txt files

Tags: quicklook, file-extensions

I would like Quick Look to treat files that have `.in` extension like regular text files, meaning show me the contents of the file after I click spacebar on them.

How can I configure my system to work that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [QLStephen](http://whomwah.github.io/qlstephen/):

```
wget https://github.com/downloads/whomwah/qlstephen/QLStephen.qlgenerator.zip
unzip QLStephen.qlgenerator.zip
mkdir -p ~/Library/QuickLook
mv QLStephen.qlgenerator ~/Library/QuickLook
qlmanage -r
```